# MySql multiplication columns with NULL rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have this SQL table:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| ID | DESCRIPTION | QUANTITY | EACH | PRICE |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
| 1  | Product 1   |     1    |  12  | 1*12  |
| 2  | Product 2   |     2    |   3  | 2* 3  |
| 3  | Prodcut 3   |   NULL   |   3  |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-------+
```

And this query:

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  (QUANTITY*EACH) AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

I want to replace **NULL** with **1** and I want to make the multiplication in the column PRICE.
I don't want to use **UPDATE** because I can't change the values in the table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `coalesce` expression to get a value instead of a `null`:

```
SELECT
  DESCRIPTION,
  QUANTITY,
  EACH,
  COALESCE(QUANTITY, 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-null value of its parameters

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION,
       QUANTITY,
       EACH,
       coalesce(QUANTITY, 1) * EACH AS PRICE
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IFNULL:

```
SELECT id, description, quantity, each,
IFNULL(quantity,1)*each AS price
FROM Table
```